# SNMP wrapper agent?

Tags: rest, snmp, net-snmp, pysnmp

So we have some internal applications that provide metrics via a RESTful api. We would like to expose this data via SNMP. What I am thinking is that at the host level an SNMP wrapper would receive a SNMPGET and then perform a HTTP request for the necessary data, translate to SNMP and reply.

Has anyone done something similar or ever heard of anyone doing something similar. Any existing programs or libraries available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people that want to do scripting or agent extensions fall to [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) since it has easy(ish)-to-use support for doing just the things you're talking about.

Within Net-SNMP, you can do it with [shell scripts](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Pass_persist) or directly [embedded perl](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tut:Extending_snmpd_using_perl).  (there are some other ways too, but those two links are the best performing and the most popular).

See the "EXTENDING AGENT FUNCTIONALITY" functionality of the [snmpd.conf](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html) manual page too.